# sum digits a number in Java

Tags: java

I have a bunch of numbers.Each digit of those numbers is concatenated n times and then summed. I have to write function which is returns 1 if sum equals number else returns 0.

```
public static int checkConcatenatedSum(int n, int catlen) {
        char[] charArray = String.valueOf(n).toCharArray();
        int[] test = new int[charArray.length];
        String[] digit = new String[charArray.length];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < catlen; i++){
                digit[j] += charArray[j];
            }
            test[j] = Integer.parseInt(digit[j]);
            sum += test[j];
        }
        if(sum == n){
            return 1;
        }
        else return 1;
    }
```

`digit[j]` begins with *null* every time.

Comment: Am I the only one who does not understand, what OP wants to achieve with this function? ^^

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize a new array of objects (String[] strs = ...) all elements in the array will be initialized to null, but you can then iterate over the array and set them all to some value (like "")

Comment: I was just typing the same thing. Not going to bother. This is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array (of `String` in this case), its elements are `null` at first.

You need to initialize the elements:

```
String[] digit = new String[charArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < digit.length) {
  digit[i] = new String();
}
```

Comment: He should probably do that in his initial iteration so he can avoid having to loop an additional N times.

Comment: @hsanders - true, but its harder to understand the concept that way

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++){
    digit[j] = new String();
    for(int i = 0; i < catlen; i++){
        digit[j] += charArray[j];
    }
    test[j] = Integer.parseInt(digit[j]);
    sum += test[j];
}
```

Other answers are right, but just a quick addition to your existing loop that achieves it without making a new loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to test if array[?] is *'null'* avoiding to create a temporary object String for Garbage Collector

```
for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < catlen; i++){
       digit[i] = digit[i] == null ? charArray[j] :  digit[i] + charArray[j];
    }
    test[j] = Integer.parseInt(digit[j]);
    sum += test[j];
}
```

**EDIT**
Your second return is erroneous (0 attempted);